# Entity Framework 4.0 - Function Import - Stored procedure Resultset

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using visual studio 2010 and with Entity Framework(EF).  I am retriving data from database and binding into Gridview through Entity Model, using stored procedures. When I execute this Stored procedure in a SQL Query, its returns columns which is generated dynamically. ie., Execute (@PivotTableSQL). @PivotTableSQL contains dynamically generated select statement. Below is my code of the Stored procedure.

But, To create Complex Type, from the Entity model browser window -> Add Function import window -> Complex --> Get Columns Information,  "The selected stored procedure return no columns." message is displayed. Please give me a solution, how to add function import and Get Column information (create complex Type) or any other alternate solution in detail. This one stopped my further development. Thanks in advance.

```
 alter PROCEDURE spGetQuestGrid
(
 @QID as int
)
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT OFF

 SET FMTONLY OFF

 Declare @optId varchar(10)
 DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

 set @optId = (select DISTINCT Optid from  QuestOptions where QID = @QID) 

 SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeaders + ', [' + cast(Caption as varchar) + ']' ,
        '[' + cast(Caption as varchar)+ ']')
        FROM OptionsDetail where OptId = @optId

 SET @PivotTableSQL = 'select * from (select  Caption,Optid  from OptionsDetail ) as datatable
        PIVOT
         ( min(Optid) FOR Caption IN ( '+ @PivotColumnHeaders + '))as Colltable'  

 Execute (@PivotTableSQL)  

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that because you execute the final statement dynamically Entity Framework cannot figure out the result set structure at design time.

There are a couple of methods you could try to overcome this:

1. Alter your sproc so the result set structure can be figured out at design time.  E.g., put the results into a temp table or table variable and select from that.
2. Create a dummy sproc with the same name and signature as the final sproc that contains a select statement which creates a result set with the desired structure. (E.g., select cast(1 as int), cast("a" as varchar(20)) ... etc.)  Refresh your entity model and add the function import - EF will see the structure and you can create the Entity to receive the results.  Now replace the dummy sproc in the database with your final version.

Hope that helps.